# Configuring CLion python root directory for auto-imports

Tags: python, clion, auto-import

My project has a directory structure like:

```
PROJECT_ROOT/
             src/
                 foo/
                     bar.py
```

I want my imports to look like:

```
from foo import bar
```

But IntelliJ's auto-import is writing:

```
from src.foo import bar
```

How do I tell IntelliJ that it should generate its imports relative to `PROJECT_ROOT/src/` rather than relative to `PROJECT_ROOT/`?

Comment: Have you tried marking the `src` directory as a [source root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-structure-dialog.html#e4286cf4) ?

Comment: @AndreyResler That option is not available to me.

Comment: Perhaps the option is only available in PyCharm, and not in CLion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root problem behind my question was that the "Mark Directory as" option was not available in the project pane. It turns out that for some reason this option will only present itself if a `CMakeLists.txt` file exists. By adding a barebones cmake file, the "Mark Directory as" option became available, and I was able to mark the `src` directory as a source root. See [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/7800097853202-Marking-Directory-as-a-python-source-root-) for details.